# Cambiar estado de cualquier checkbox de una una tabla

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hola buenas tardes esta vez me tope con un detalle que no puedo solucionar. Al dar clic sobre un checkbox se debe disparar una función que verifica si algún candidato ya esta asociado a una vacante pero lo que no sale bien es que al detectar uno que ya esta vinculado, se muestra una modal que indique que ya esta asociado y después de eso poner en falso la propiedad checked. Obtengo el check a través del id. Me emocione al ver que lo hace con el primer elemento de la tabla pero si continuo con los demás esos si quedan marcados si es que se activa el modal.

Este es el código:

```
$('#formDatosVacantes').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
  var buttons = "";
  var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();

  buttons = table.buttons( ['.asociar'] );

  var idVacantes = $(this).val();

  var idCanPros = <?= json_encode($idCP,JSON_HEX_QUOT | 
                      JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
                  ) ?>;

  alert(idCanPros);

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxVerificaVacante,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      idVacantes : idVacantes,
      idCanPros  : idCanPros,
      _csrf  : _csrfToken
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data.mensajes != 0){
        $("#texto").html(data.mensajes);
        document.getElementById("idVacante").checked = false;
        buttons.disable();
        $('#existeEnVacante').modal('show');
      }
    },
    error: function(exception){
      console.log('error' + exception);
    }
  });

  if(this.checked==true){
    buttons.enable();
  }else{
    buttons.disable();
  }});
```

¿Alguien sabe que se puede hacer? Es como si detectara solo el primer checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno veo varias cosas en tu código:

1. Como tienes una tabla supongo que tienes varios `checkbox` y veo en tu código que los seleccionas por medio de un id.

   **Recuerda:** cuando hay varios elementos que van a compartir el mismo nombre en el sitio se debe usar `class` y no `id`. El `id` es un identificador único e irrepetible y es por esta razón que tu código solo funciona correctamente con el primer `checkbox` por que cuando tienes varios elementos con el mismo `id` el sistema siempre va a interactuar con el primero que encuentre ignorando así el resto.
2. Si estas usando jQuery ¿para que utilizas un selector de JavaScript nativo? Simplemente usa jQuery de principio a fin.
3. Para checkear o quitar el checked de un checkbox se utiliza el método `prop()` de jQuery.

**Ejemplo funcional:**

**NOTA:** agregué un `setTimeout()` con un pequeño lapso de tiempo para que puedas ver como se checkea y como se quita el checked del `checkbox`.

```js
$('#formDatosVacantes').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".idVacante").prop('checked', false);
        $('#existeEnVacante').modal('show');
    }, 200);

});
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="formDatosVacantes" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Check</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Usuario 1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" class="idVacante"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>usuario 2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" class="idVacante"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Usuario 3</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" class="idVacante"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Usuario 4</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" class="idVacante"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="existeEnVacante" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Y así debería de quedar tu código** (recuerda cambiar los `id` de los `checkbox` por `class`)

```
$('#formDatosVacantes').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
  var buttons = "";
  var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();

  buttons = table.buttons( ['.asociar'] );

  var idVacantes = $(this).val();

  var idCanPros = <?= json_encode($idCP,JSON_HEX_QUOT | 
                      JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
                  ) ?>;

  alert(idCanPros);

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxVerificaVacante,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      idVacantes : idVacantes,
      idCanPros  : idCanPros,
      _csrf  : _csrfToken
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data.mensajes != 0){
        $("#texto").html(data.mensajes);
        $(".idVacante").prop('checked', false);
        buttons.disable();
        $('#existeEnVacante').modal('show');
      }
    },
    error: function(exception){
      console.log('error' + exception);
    }
  });

  if(this.checked==true){
    buttons.enable();
  }else{
    buttons.disable();
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo. Voy a fijarme más en esos detalles.